# Multiple domain names on a single server

Tags: apache, ubuntu-12.04

*Sorry my English*

I have Ubuntu 12.04 openVZ VPS, with Apache and Passenger installed, to run Ruby site. That site have several faces which available (not yet) from different domains. In */etc/apache2/sites-available* I created file *site1.com* which contains this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName site1.com
    DocumentRoot /home/happy_buddha/Sites/rubysite/public
        <Directory /home/happy_buddha/Sites/rubysite/public>
        AllowOverride all
        Options -MultiViews
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Previously I created A record on *site1.com* domain which contains server's ip.
Now if I going to *site1.com* browser's window contains this:
[image: Browser's window]

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

you can not give virtual host name same as other's.

Like you said `" I created A record on site1.com domain which contains server's ip."` then you have to change your virtual host's name. Try with different name. for eg `site2.com` or `site1.local`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have `NameVirutalHost *:80` set in your apache config - this will probably be in `/etc/apache2/ports.conf` on your Ubuntu server.

It sounds like the new site you created is acting as the default virtual host which is why you can't see the site you had before.

That said, if you actually visit site1.com, then I might expect to see the result you get, I don't know where the config is done for interpreting the ruby code but this *might* need to be part of the VirtualHost too.

Comment: Looks like *ports.conf* is OK, line *NameVirtualHost *:80* exists